# s3boto and presigned s3 urls

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm using django-storages and s3boto.

I'm able to generate presigned urls that expire after x seconds. This functions as desired and the url no longer works after x seconds. The url looks like this.

```
https://mybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/Users/sale-20200727053948.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQVNWS6JIFDS34635fasdFS%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200727T061840Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=e26a5521268623513182e170fda433kj3lfklejfaslkjdsf
```

Now, I've found that I'm able to remove the content after the '?' in the string to get the following url, and it never expires.

```
https://mybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/Users/sale-20200727053948.jpg
```

What setting do I need to ensure that the image is not accessible without the perameters that are on the presigned URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**.

If that object can be read without any authentication, then at least one of the following is true:

- The bucket has a **Bucket Policy** that is granting public access to all or some of the bucket.
- The object has an **Access Control List (ACL)** that grants public access to the object. This might have been set when the object was uploaded, or afterwards via the 'Make Public' command in the S3 management console.

To test, **manually upload a new object to the bucket** and then access it via the displayed URL. (Click the displayed link. Do not use the 'Open' button, since it provides a Signed URL.) If that object is immediately accessible, then access is being granted via a Bucket Policy. If it is not accessible, then the above file must have been given a `public-read` ACL during upload.